# Unable to change the value of a persistent variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, persistent

I have a function defined in one of the simulink function blocks. In that function I have defined some persistent variables and wish to change their values based on certain condition. The values of those persistent variable isnt changing. Here is my code,

```
function [er,mem,phi_hat_dot,hdot,ldot,x_hat,x_til1,...
    x_til2,f_hat,g_hat,x_hat_dot,h_bar,ns]= ident(x,u,h,...
    l,phi_hat,gain)
persistent i Z x_tj;            % initialized persistent values
if isempty(i)
    i=0;
end
if isempty(Z)
    Z=zeros(5,15);
end
if isempty(x_tj)
    %si=size(Z);
    x_tj=zeros(length(x),15);
end
Gamma=gain(1);a=gain(2);A=gain(3); % gains
x1=x(1);x2=x(2);                   % state variable
z=[x1,x2,x1*(x1^2+x2^2),x2*(x1^2+x2^2),u]';
hdot=-a*h+z;
ldot=-A*l+x;
ns=1+h'*h+l'*l;
x_bar=x/ns;h_bar=h/ns;l_bar=l/ns;
x_hat=phi_hat*h_bar+a*l_bar;
e=x_hat-x_bar;
%%%%%%%%%Memory Stack%%%%%%%
while i<15               %This is the place where I am altering persistent variables
    Z(:,i+1)=h_bar;
    x_tj(:,i+1)=x_bar;
    i=i+1;
end
mem=x_tj;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%Error Stack%%%%%%%%%%%
%Gamma=102;
si=size(Z);
er=zeros(length(x),si(2));
if i>=15
    for j=1:si(2)
        er(:,j)=x_hat-x_tj(:,j);
    end
    phi_hat_dot=-Gamma*e*h_bar'-Gamma*er*Z';
else
    phi_hat_dot=-Gamma*e*h_bar';
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%Update Law%%%%%%%%%%%
x_til1=x-x_hat;
x_til2=x_bar-x_hat;
f_hat=phi_hat(:,1:4)*z(1:4);
g_hat=phi_hat(:,5)*1;
x_hat_dot=f_hat+g_hat*u;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the variable `i`, and following your code, `i` will only ever change during model initialization.

That is, at `t=0`, the code gets called and

- initially `i = 0;`
- then in *Memory Stack* `i` will increment from `0` to `15`

Since you don't alter `i` anywhere else, the above means that since `i` is persistent, at all other times it will have a value of `15`.

Hence the `while i < 15` loop is never executed (after initialization), and you never change the values of `Z` and `x_tj` (after initialization).  It also means that in *Error Stack* the `i >= 15` code will always get executed.

If the above is not happening (which it must be) then what are you seeing, and what are you expecting?

Also note that you can simplify the initialization a little.  At all times when `i` is empty, `Z` and `x_tj` will always be empty, so there's no real reason to check them.

```
if isempty(i)
    i=0;
    Z=zeros(5,15);
    %si=size(Z);
    x_tj=zeros(length(x),15);
end
```